# Print all tracks during the travel between nodes

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

here is a code to do breadth first search and print all roads we visit
I got some incomplete results , but the results have 10 or 11 nodes which is most of node doesn't appear , I get result to 6 nodes .
unfortunately the list have only this roads :
[0, 2, 3, 1, 3] [0, 2, 4, 2][0, 2, 3, 5, 3][0, 2, 6, 7, 6]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 9, 5][0, 2, 4, 5, 10, 5] [0, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10]
so how It can see the list contain all nodes that mean it will contain 11 nodes, any help please

```
import copy
graph = {
  0 : [2],
  1 : [3],
  2 : [0,3,4,6],
  3 : [1,2,5],
  4 : [2,5,7],
  5 : [3,4,9,10],
  6 : [2,7,8],
  7 : [4,6,9],
  8 : [6,9],
  9 : [5,7,8,10],
  10 : [5,9]
}
visited = [] # List for visited nodes.
queue = []     #Initialize a queue
list = [[0]]
def bfs(visited, graph, node): #function for BFS
  visited.append(node)
  queue.append(node)

  while queue:          # Creating loop to visit each node
    m = queue.pop(0) 
    print (m, end = "-->")
    for neighbour in graph[m]:
        temp = []
        for raw in list:
            if raw[-1]==m :#condition to add node to the right road 
                    temp = copy.deepcopy(raw) #i.e list =[2,1,3,4],[2,5,1,3,5],... 
                    raw.append(neighbour)# if m= 4 => add neighbour  
                    break                # so become [2,1,3,4,neibour]
        
        if neighbour not in visited:
            visited.append(neighbour)
            queue.append(neighbour)
        if temp != '' :  # here i save the old roads to edit it for a new road
            list.append(temp) 

# Driver Code
print("Following is the Breadth-First Search")
bfs(visited, graph, 0)    # function calling
for i in list:       # here i want only the roads more than 6 nodes 
  if len(i) >= 6:
    print(i)
```

Comment: For anyone who needs it, the answer should be `0 2 4 7 6 8 9 10 5 3 1`

Comment: Why would temp ever be equal to `''`? The `if temp != ''` statement will always be true.

Comment: yeah exactly  0 2 4 7 6 8 9 10 5 3 1

Comment: temp make a copy for the road , for example,[9,1,2,3] so the code add 5 become [9,1,2,3,5] and save copy [9,1,2,3] because maybe 3 have more children ..so another children for 3  will be [9,1,2,3,0] [9,1,2,3,5]  .... and again copy [9,1,2,3]

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. `temp` is a list correct? So why would it ever have the value of `''`? The if statement is faulty, and will always execute because `temp` will never be equal to `''`

Comment: the code work properly  for indirect  map ...suppose the graph = {
  '5' : ['3','7'],
  '3' : ['2', '4'],
  '7' : ['8'],
  '2' : [],
  '4' : ['8'],
  '8' : []
}  the answer will be Following is the Breadth-First Search
5-->3-->7-->2-->4-->8-->['5', '3', '2']
['5', '7', '8']
['5', '3', '4', '8']
['5', '3', '4']....because there is line from 5 to 3 , but no line from 3 to 5

Comment: if there any code to save all roads between nodes BFS or DFS or whatever  ..please share